# ngClass not rendering properly

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am loading a todos list, every todo has a flag field which if true the `ng-class` should apply. When loading data into the page `ng-class` is applied if I use `ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted=='true'}"`, but then it doesn't work when I play with the checkboxes.

On the other hand if I use `ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}"` instead (without the quotes on the `true`), it loads the data without applying the `ng-class` at the beginning, means loading all as if they are false, but then it works fine when playing with the checkboxes.

It has been driving me crazy, couldn't figure out why.

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}" class="editing">
        <div class="view" >
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-click="complete(todo)" ng-model="todo.isCompleted" ng-checked="{{todo.isCompleted}}">
            <label ng-hide="isEditing" ng-dblclick="isEditing = !isEditing">{{todo.title}}</label>
            <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(todo)"></button>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" ng-show="isEditing" ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="isEditing = !isEditing;edit(todo);">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.complete = function(todo) {
    $scope.insertTodo(todo, UPDATE);
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does compete() do? Show us the controller code.

Comment: Please check my EDIT. I simply go and save the changes on the flag to the database.

Comment: `{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}` is supposed to work just fine. Something else is happening, maybe your data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like your **server** is returning the **boolean** values as **strings**, that's why your bindings don't work...

You can either change your server's return values (**preferred**) or add `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to your check box and keep the binding on `ng-class` using the string comparison:

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted=='true'}" class="editing">
        <div class="view" >
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-click="complete(todo)" ng-model="todo.isCompleted" ng-checked="{{todo.isCompleted}}" ng-true-value="'true'"  ng-false-value="'false'">
            <label ng-hide="isEditing" ng-dblclick="isEditing = !isEditing">{{todo.title}}</label>
            <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(todo)"></button>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" ng-show="isEditing" ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="isEditing = !isEditing;edit(todo);">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked like a charm! It was definitely a string/boolean issue. For commodity I've added the two ng-true-value and ng-false-value, so I don't have to go through all the changes in the controller. Thanks.

Comment: Great, the important thing is that you understanded what was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to change

```
ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}"
```

to

```
ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted}"
```

Or, one of those

```
ng-class="todo.isCompleted ? 'completed' : ''"  
ng-class="{true: 'completed', false: ''}[todo.isCompleted]"
```

Comment: This way they get loaded with the ng-class applied as if they are all false.

Comment: The last one worked, but sometimes it wouldn't. Couldn't find the criteria but I would say is related to the boolean/string issue mentioned in the accepted solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good that the problem is fixed!